# Netbeans 6.9 for PHP. Error highlighting

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I'm currently using Netbeans for PHP work.

I would like to know if there is  a way to edit the current method Netbeans displays coding errors - it currents underlines the offending code in red, and places an error badge in the line column.

What I'd prefer is if the offending code line is highlighted in red, much like it is in Dreamweaver CS5 and PHPDesigner 7.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be achieved, without changing the way Netbeans works internally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can (At least with NetBeans 7 you can)...

Go to:
**Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax**
Choose your language(s), and look for the **Error** Category.

You can change the Font, Font styling and Background color